# Preventing sprite overlap

Tags: objective-c, sprite

I'm trying to create a game. In this game I want the user to be able to place down sprite icons through touch. However, I want to make it so make it so that if the user clicks an area with an already exist sprite, that the new sprite created through touch will not overlap with the pre existing sprite, but rather go to the closest position.

EDIT: So right now, what I'm doing is every time I add a sprite into the view, I also add it to a sprite array which will keep track of all of the sprites currently created using

`[array addObject:newObject];`

So if the user creates a new object, I'm going to first check the position by looping through the array and then checking the x and y positions.

```
for(SKSpriteNode __strong *object in Objects){
    if(touchedObject.position.x != object.position.x 
      && touchedObject.position.y != object.position.y){
     //add the sprite 
     }
}
```

the first problem i'm having is that the position is returning 0.0000

Comment: Edit your question with code. You problem occurs actually many certainties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code stuff isn't enough to find out sprite exist or not on touch location. You have to implement some SKNode methods for detection. Remember, SKSpriteNode is inherit from SKNode class so you can use directly SKNode methods. Utilize following methods,

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromNode:(SKNode *)node
 - (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)p
 - (BOOL)intersectsNode:(SKNode *)node
 - (SKNode *)nodeAtPoint:(CGPoint)p
```

Will helpful you solve problem.
For more information you need to go through [apple doc.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKNode)

Comment: Thanks I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was getting the node position relative to the frame which was why it was at 0. I had to convert it

`CGPoint position = [self convertPoint:object.position fromNode:self];`

Now i'm trying to figure out how to find the dimensions of the node so that the sprite dont overlap/stack ontop of each other

Comment: Thanks I used the intersectsNode to correct the overlapping problem